# Wireless connection is not working

Tags: networking

The wireless connection in Ubuntu 16.04 is not working. Even after enabling WiFi, in "edit connection" only the Ethernet wired connection option is available. In additional drivers the options contain only 'unknown source- using processor microcode firmware...'  How do I enable WiFi connection?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry your question doesn't specify the WIFI device installed in your computer. can you give us the output of "lspci" in the terminal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

worked on my macbook

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot if it does not connect post a new file from the script.

No internet:

Download the b43updated.zip file to a usb flash drive then drag and drop the file to your ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here.

Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe -rv b43 
sudo modprobe -v b43
if it does not come on reboot.
```

Comment: Why do you think OP has a Broadcom adapter that requires b43 firmware?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `intel-microcode` to fix the 'unknown source- using processor microcode firmware...' error.

Start `Synaptic` from the Unity dashboard. First click the Reload icon, then click the Search icon and enter `intel-microcode`. In the single result displayed, place a checkmark in front of the name, then click the Apply icon. Quit Synaptic and restart the computer.

To see intel-microcode in action, in terminal, type `dmsg|grep microcode`.

Lastly, if you installed any software drivers for your wi-fi card, you probably have to disable `secure boot` in your BIOS to make it work in 16.04.

Cheers, Al

Comment: OK, removed :).

Comment: Intel microcode is not related to Wi-Fi.

Comment: @Pilot6, it's related to the error message that he's getting. And yes, it CAN effect wi-fi, as I worked with another OP (and chilli was involved) and it DID fix his wi-fi. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi, none of the answers worked :( only the wired Ethernet connection is working. In 'edit connections' wireless option is not displayed at all.

Comment: In the network icon in the top panel, does `Enable Wi-Fi` have a checkmark in front of the name?

Comment: Yes enable WiFi is checkmarked.

Comment: What happens if you open 'Edit Connections', click the ADD button, and select Wi-Fi as the type? Can you create a wireless profile for your adapter and have it work? Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes I can create a wireless profile in edit connections, but I have no idea as to what details I should fill in.

Comment: The network controller that's being used is ralink corp. RT3090 wireless. Kernel driver in use: rt280pci. WiFi is still not working! How to fix it?

Comment: Start `terminal` from the Unity dash. In terminal, type `rfkill list`. All responses should be `no`. Let me know if there are any `yes`. If there are `yes` responses, in terminal, type `rfkill unblock all`, and see if the responses to `rfkill list` turn to `no`. See if your wireless works now. Cheers, Al

Comment: Also, again, in terminal, type `dpkg -s linux-firmware`, and see if `status` shows as `installed`, or if the command returns `not installed`. Cheers, Al

Comment: I tried rfkill unblock all, even after that the harblock states yes. At first the soft block was yes, after I tried few commands now the harblock is yes and soft block is no for wireless.

Comment: If you have a laptop, look for a small switch along the edge of the laptop that's used to switch wireless on/off. It's easy to miss, and it's easy to bump into the off position. If you don't have a physical switch, you may have a function key (like F12, or something else) to do the same thing. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: No there's no switch as such. The Ubuntu version I'm using is 16.04. So I guess this version is not compatible for wireless networks, atleast that's what I heard from a laptop service station near home.

Comment: It should be able to work. Somebody else may need to chime in. Did you check the linux-firmware that I suggested earlier? Did you check for a function key? The hardblock from rfkill is the big clue. @chili555, can you help Monica? ps: don't believe the local laptop station. Cheers, Al

Comment: @Pilot6, can you please help Monica? Cheers, Al

Comment: @a1computers, can you please help Monica? Cheers, Al